# Passing a variable from beginning to end - Paypal

Tags: paypal

I'be been at this for days and i cant seem to figure it out. All i want to do is when subscribe button is pushed, a variable is send ( post get i dont care ) payment is completed and landed on the success page, with my variable!

From what i can gather this should be able to do it:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="0000000">
<Input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php md5($code.microtime()); ?>"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any help much appreciated ( and yes I've read paypal and sandbox documentation, just not that good at reading. )

Answer (score 9):

The variables 'custom' and 'invoice' are both what PayPal calls "pass-through" variables.  PayPal doesn't do anything with them, it just passes them back to you in any IPN notifications that you receive regarding that transaction (someone makes a payment, a chargeback, etc).

I can confirm personally that this works correctly as of right now using the 'custom' variable.  I am using their Standard (free) payment solution currently...

How are you monitoring the IPN notification to see what variables are being posted back to you?

***Edit - Additional Info Added Below:***

*I wanted to expand on this a bit as I was very recently caught by an issue related to pass-through variables!*

**The 'invoice' variable must be UNIQUE per transaction**; PayPal will only allow 1 completed payment to come through per UNIQUE invoice string.  Any subsequent attempts to checkout (that come in with an already-paid 'invoice' variable) will immediately be shown a "This invoice was already paid for." message.

The 'custom' variable on the other hand is NOT required to be unique and is intended to strictly be used as a pass-through variable - in most cases this is what you want to use when you're just looking for the 'pass-through' functionality.

Hope that helps - the uniqueness issue recently cost me nearly a full day of a broken checkout process on a personal project of mine!

Answer (score 0):

Missing an `echo`.  Instead of this:

```
<?php md5($code.microtime()); ?>
```

Try this:

```
<?php echo md5($code.microtime()); ?>
```

Comment: Will it pass it back throught $_POST['custom'] ??

Comment: Still no luck. nothing is sent.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will not process your custom data, so instead of sending it to them and getting it back, just store it in your own database. Associate the data with the transaction using `invoice` as the key.

In your landing page, you can get the `invoice` from PayPal transaction. Then you can fetch the data from your own database that referred by that `invoice` id.

Comment: Does this principle apply for the Standard payment option (this is when you host the button but it takes the user to Paypal to complete the transaction) ?

Comment: @Joel you can read the Paypal standard API. Any variables besides their specification will not processed by Paypal and might be discarded when user redirected to success page. `invoice` field can be used to track your application's invoice_id, and in success page, you can use it to fetch additional data and display it to the user.

Comment: Turns out there is a "custom" field for just this.

Comment: Yes, but it just one field. If you only need to put one custom value, then you can use it. But for more than one value, it's better to kept it in application, and only save the id into invoice field. Both invoice and custom field is not processed by Paypal. Invoice need to be unique across transaction, so it can also track if customer already pay for the certain transaction or the previous transaction failed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be no seems to get CUSTOM being passed through in Sandbox

Shame PayPal is not that good as we all thought

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value=<?php echo "\"".md5($code.microtime())."\""; ?>/>
```

There was a missing echo and also the quotes are around the value, not the php